# block function execution during setTimeout

Tags: javascript, settimeout

I have a function that I call when I press a button. My goal is to print "hello" in the console after 5 seconds and, if I press the button during the 5 seconds of waiting, nothing at all.

The problem is that, if I press the button while i'm waiting the 5 seconds, in the console I still get more than one "hello". What am I doing wrong?

Here is the Javascript code:

```
function foo(){
    var block = false;
    if(!block){
        block = true;
        myVar = setTimeout(checkAgain, 5000);
    }
    function checkAgain(){
        console.log("hello");
        block = false;
    }
}
```

And the HTML:

```
<button id="button" onClick="foo();">Click me!</button>
```

Comment: Your `block` is a local variable, not a global one/on the scope above.

Comment: `block` is a local variable, so it will always be false at the beginning.

Comment: If you're using lodash then [debounce](https://lodash.com/docs/#debounce) with a trailing invocation looks like what you're trying to do

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to manually handle the "block", you can just cancel the call with `clearTimeout`. This seems to be more natural for me - when you click once you say "call this function in 5 seconds", and when you click it again you say "don't call it".

```js
var timeout = null;
var button = document.querySelector("#btn");

button.onclick = function()
{
  if (timeout) 
  {
    clearTimeout(timeout);
    timeout = null;
  }
  else 
  {
    timeout = setTimeout(function() { 
      timeout = null;
      run();
    }, 1000); // should be 5000, just for test
  }
};

function run()
{  
  console.log("Hello world");
}
```

```html
<input type="button" id="btn" value="Click me">
```

Comment: This is an interesting solution, I had not thought about it

Answer (score 0):

You're not doing anything to block subsequent calls. `block` is a **local variable** inside `foo`, so there's a different one for each call to `foo`.

Instead, you have to have `block` outside `foo`:

```js
var myVar;
var block = false;
function foo(){
    if(!block){
        block = true;
        myVar = setTimeout(checkAgain, 5000);
    }
    function checkAgain(){
        console.log("hello");
        block = false;
    }
}
document.getElementById("btn").addEventListener("click", foo);
```

```html
<input type="button" id="btn" value="Click me">
```

That also means that `checkAgain` doesn't have to be recreated for every call to `foo`, since it doesn't need anything local to `foo` anymore:

```js
var myVar;
var block = false;
function foo(){
    if(!block){
        block = true;
        myVar = setTimeout(checkAgain, 5000);
    }
}
function checkAgain(){
    console.log("hello");
    block = false;
}
document.getElementById("btn").addEventListener("click", foo);
```

```html
<input type="button" id="btn" value="Click me">
```

*(I assume all of this is in a scoping function or module so these aren't globals.)*

That said, the button will remain active, giving the user the impression he/she could click it. Instead, you might consider making it possible for `foo` to disable and re-enable the button.

Answer (score 0):

that is because you have defined variable 'block' in the scope of the function 'foo' and it is been initiated again every time you call the function. the correct implementation is:

```
var block = false;

function foo(){
  if (!block) {
    block = true;
    myVar = setTimeout(checkAgain, 5000);
  }

  function checkAgain() {
    console.log("hello");
    block = false;
  }
}
```